# Running Windows programs in Linux

Tags: .net, linux, executable

I've developed a Notepad kinda Windows application in VB.NET using Visual Studio 2008. Is it possible for me to run the file in the Linux environment if I install the mono-develop package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all the functions you have used are supported by mono, you should be able to.

Check your application with [MOMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) (The Mono Migration Analyzer) to be sure.

One difference from windows is that you can't simply call the executable - you need to call `mono executablename.exe`.

Comment: How do I know that the functions I wrote are supported by Mono?

Comment: @Arjun: IIRC, Mono provides a tool that can check your code and report any possible problems with converting.

Comment: Note that this will not **run** the Windows-compiled binary. This will tell you whether your application can be compiled for Linux using Mono or not. If it can be, you can then re-compile the project using mono-develop to get it working on Linux.

Comment: @Felix - however, if there are no conflicts the runtime will be able to run the application _as is_. See the technical FAQ: http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical

Comment: You can definitely run Windows compiled CIL binaries in linux; that is the whole point of the CLI.

Comment: It should be possible to configure binfmt_misc to execute CIL binaries using mono as the interpreter, so that the executable can be directly executed.